# Debian Squeezy on VirtualBox apt-get not working 0% but ping works

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, debian

I have problem with `apt-get update` on my Debian Squeezy machine on Windows 10 host - internet bridged adapter wifi.

Example:

```
apt-get update
0% Connected to ftp.pl.debian.org 153.19.251.221
```

and so all the time...

After a while there is:

```
Failed to initialize connection ftp.pl.debian.org:80 (2001:4070:1::fafb) - connect (101: the network is unavailable)
```

But ping to 153.19.251.221 it's works.

Example 2:

```
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.3.3.tar.xz
```

it does not work

```
timeout waiting for a connection
```

What is the problem?

My ifconfig

```
...
inet addr:192.168.0.112 Bcast: 192.168.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
...
```

Last message from dmesg

```
[33971.214920] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

Guest routing table:

```
Dest          Gateway   Genmask        Flags Metric  Ref Use Iface 
192.168.0.0   0.0.0.0   255.255.255.0  U  0  0  0  eth0
0.0.0.0       192.168.0.1  0.0.0.0  UG  0  0  0  eth0
```

Windows routing table:

```
route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 24...04 7d 7b e8 ae 4f ......Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
  2...9c 4e 36 36 4f 91 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 64...9e 4e 36 36 4f 90 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2
 28...0a 00 27 00 00 00 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
 22...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 13...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
 14...00 50 56 c0 00 04 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet4
 19...00 50 56 c0 00 05 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet5
  7...00 50 56 c0 00 06 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet6
  4...00 50 56 c0 00 07 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet7
 20...9c 4e 36 36 4f 90 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2200
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 27...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
 29...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
 23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 10...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
  3...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #10
 35...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #11
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.104     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.104    281
    192.168.0.104  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.104    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.104    281
     192.168.44.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.44.1    276
     192.168.44.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.1    276
   192.168.44.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.1    276
     192.168.52.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.52.1    276
     192.168.52.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.1    276
   192.168.52.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.1    276
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.88.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.88.1    276
     192.168.88.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.88.1    276
   192.168.88.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.88.1    276
    192.168.174.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.174.1    276
    192.168.174.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.174.1    276
  192.168.174.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.174.1    276
    192.168.186.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.186.1    276
    192.168.186.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.186.1    276
  192.168.186.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.186.1    276
    192.168.254.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.254.1    276
    192.168.254.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.254.1    276
  192.168.254.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.254.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.104    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.254.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.52.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.174.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.88.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.44.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.186.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.104    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.254.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.52.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.174.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.88.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.44.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.186.1    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 23    306 ::/0                     On-link
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 23    306 2001::/32                On-link
 23    306 2001:0:9d38:6abd:149c:84f:3f57:ff97/128
                                    On-link
 28    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 14    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 13    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 22    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  7    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 19    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 23    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  4    276 fe80::9b6:c440:4a32:9b57/128
                                    On-link
 23    306 fe80::149c:84f:3f57:ff97/128
                                    On-link
 28    266 fe80::241d:cce0:b999:baf/128
                                    On-link
 22    276 fe80::3d53:7d8d:b803:5f0e/128
                                    On-link
  7    276 fe80::9044:2e90:eac5:5bc3/128
                                    On-link
 14    276 fe80::909c:a233:f2b4:b621/128
                                    On-link
 20    281 fe80::91c3:3fa0:a53:3997/128
                                    On-link
 13    276 fe80::aceb:9eac:443d:a47f/128
                                    On-link
 19    276 fe80::ad98:e8c8:7061:646c/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 28    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 23    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 14    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  4    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 13    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 22    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 19    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Please post the routing tables of the host and of the guest

Comment: Ok. It's done. Check please.

Comment: What happens when you ping Google.com from this Linux VM?  Sounds like a dns issue to me

Comment: Also, that dmesg log is strange considering your routing table has a bunch of IPv6 routes.  Another point that is interesting is when you try to resolve the apt get repo, it is returning an IPv6 address.

Comment: Problem solved, I do not know why but antivirus blocked.